# BOOTSTRAP: nav bar is glitching

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and am learning. I hate the demo examples where it breaks the semantic to make it look nice. Anyways...

I worked on a sample site, [theavcorp.com](http://theavcorp.com), and tried not to "break the semantic's bank" while learning bootstrap. However...

The top navigation bar is not behaving properly. I am using a

> .navbar-fixed-top

navigation. However, instead of showing the whole content of `<main>` BEFORE scrolling down, it covers the content of `<main>` as soon as it loads the page.

Can you please help me figure out what's causing the misbehavior? Perhaps I am missing a class or an element or container element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bootstrap.min.css find the following and add `margin-top:80px;`

```
.container .jumbotron, .container-fluid .jumbotron {
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

Comment: simply adding this in a CSS file, after loading bootstrap will do. No need to look within bootstrap.min.css. Question, isn't this a patch rather than fixing what the cause is?

Comment: In [this official bootstrap demo](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/), they use `padding-top:70px;` on the `body`. [Check here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/navbar-fixed-top.css)
You can add it to the body if you want. It is not a fix. It's how CSS works